# How to link js datetime picker to input tag with id &/or class of minDate in an mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am currently trying to make a input tag display a calendar with jquery on an ASP.net MVC. I am not sure if i am linking it correctly as I am new to MVC's.

The input tag i am using for the datetimepicker:

```
    <input class="minDate" id="minDate"/>
```

the script inside the page along with the link of the datetimepicker from this [site](http://mugifly.github.io/jquery-simple-datetimepicker/)

```
     @section Scripts
   {
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(function () {
        $('#minDate').appendDtpicker({
            "inline": true,
            "futureOnly": true
        });
    });
     </script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.simple-dtpicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
     }
```

From the example of the site, the calendar should appear on clicking the input box. But sadly nothing appears.

I want to know if i have linked the JS wrong? Do i need to use getScript instead of a script tag? and If that is fine am i calling it wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ask for the library before using it.

Comment: Ah yes they have a link to an ajax google api library. adding that and the css made it work. Silly me. Thank you.